# 3x+1 on arithmetic chains, tree pruning and NestList

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, function-construction, functional-style

Given the following function `Collatz`:

```
Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /;  EvenQ[m] && EvenQ[d]] := Subscript[m/2, d/2]
Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /;  OddQ[m] && EvenQ[d]] := Subscript[3 m + 1, 3 d]
Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /;  OddQ[d]] := 
    Collatz /@ {Subscript[m, 2 d], Subscript[m + d, 2 d]}
```

The immediate question that crops up, once `Collatz` is made `Listable` to handle the branching - is to manage the trajectories. This includes identifying and filtering cycles (ie, periodic orbits) from the transition graph.

The first 5 iterates given the initial state `Subscript[1,1]` (the chain of natural numbers 1,2,3...) is:

```
Column@ NestList[Collatz,Subscript[1, 1],5]

(* Out[1]= Subscript[1, 1]
{Subscript[1, 2],Subscript[2, 2]}
{Subscript[4, 6],Subscript[1, 1]}
{Subscript[2, 3],{Subscript[1, 2],Subscript[2, 2]}}
{{Subscript[2, 6],Subscript[5, 6]},{Subscript[4, 6],Subscript[1, 1]}}
{{Subscript[1, 3],Subscript[16, 18]},{Subscript[2, 3],{Subscript[1, 2],Subscript[2, 2]}}} *)
```

Any suggestions for functional approaches to filter out cycles, in other words, states that are repeated in the output of `NestList` but are not observable at the level of a single call to `Collatz`? In the above simulation, `Subscript[1,1]` should be filtered out after the 2nd iteration.

Recall, vertices of the transition graph are the chains `Subscript[n,d]` while the arcs link inputs of `Collatz` with its output chain(s).

Comment: Did you try _NestWhileList[f,expr,test,All]_?

Comment: Isn't this an unusual way of stating the Collatz conjecture? I recall that it only has one parameter. What's the subscript doing here?

Comment: @Sjoerd If Eddington could get new physical constants out of thin air, I don't believe adding a few constants to Collatz would hurt much ...

Comment: @Sjoerd, it's the same dynamics but in a modular arithmetic coordinate system. There are no (free) parameters in the 3x+1 problem. However, generalizations are considered. Only 2 of the fundamental open conjectures listed in Lagarias's book refer to 3x+1 itself. Conway proved that the limiting generalization of this class of problems is undecidable.

Comment: @belisarius, NestWhileList doesn't address the issue. It may of course be used to selectively terminate the computation. However, what is needed here is tree pruning at each iteration, otherwise, redundant states accumulate (again, in the arithmetic chain state space)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get the non repeated terminal symbols after round N by using the following (not optimized)

```
Collatz[Null] = Null;
Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /; EvenQ[m] && EvenQ[d]] := 
  Collatz[Subscript[m, d]] = check@Subscript[m/2, d/2];

Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /; OddQ[m] && EvenQ[d]] := 
  Collatz[Subscript[m, d]] = check@Subscript[3 m + 1, 3 d];

Collatz[Subscript[m_, d_] /; OddQ[d]] := 
  Collatz[Subscript[m, d]] = 
   Collatz /@ {check@Subscript[m, 2 d], check@Subscript[m + d, 2 d]};

Collatz1[x__] := (p = (DownValues@Collatz /. 
      HoldPattern[_[q_] :> _] :> q)[[2 ;; -4]]; Collatz[x])

check[t_] := If[Cases[p, t, Infinity] == {}, t, Null]

SetAttributes[Collatz, Listable];
SetAttributes[Collatz1, Listable];

NestList[Collatz1, Subscript[1, 1], 12][[-1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but there seems no difference in behavior between Collatz and Collatz1

Comment: @alancalvitti After more than one month I really don't remember